# Make container shrink-to-fit child elements as they wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out how flexbox works (supposed to work?…) for cases like below:

```css
.holder {
  width: 500px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.v2 {
  width: 320px;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="child">At a glance</div>
  <div class="child">After coverage ends</div>
  <div class="child">Forms &amp; documents</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="holder v2">
  <div class="child">At a glance</div>
  <div class="child">After coverage ends</div>
  <div class="child">Forms &amp; documents</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="holder v2">
  <div class="child">At a
    <br>glance</div>
  <div class="child">After coverage
    <br>ends</div>
  <div class="child">Forms &amp;
    <br>documents</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gmu6rr9o/20/)

The problem is that when there's enough space to fit elements, I'm getting a nice tight-fitted children, with even spacing between. (first, top div block)

However, when there's no enough space and text inside children starts wrapping, it all kinda goes in a weird direction - children are not tightly fit anymore, and even though after wrapping, there's enough space around flex children, because there are not properly fit anymore, space-around doesn't really have a chance to work as well  (second div block)

However still, IF I add manual line breaks at places where the automatic line breaks occur, everything gets laid out as it "should"… (bottom, third block)

What I'd like is to always have children tightly fitted within their boxes (black borders), and whatever space is left, would be distributed evenly between them, without me having to add manual line breaks (which is not an option in my case)

Is it possible at all?…

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In CSS, the parent container doesn't know when its children wrap. Hence, it continues scaling its size oblivious to what's going on inside.

Put another way, the browser renders the container on the initial cascade. It doesn't reflow the document when a child wraps.

That's why the container doesn't shrink-wrap the narrower layout. It just continues on as if nothing wrapped, as evidenced by the reserved space on the right.

The maximum length of the horizontal white space is the length of the element(s) that the container was expecting to be there.

In the following demo, whitespace can be seen coming and going as the window is re-sized horizontally: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/qh3oybq5/)

You'll need a JavaScript solution (see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33246364/3597276) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14597951/3597276))... or CSS media queries (see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811002/3597276)).

When dealing with wrapping text, `text-align: right` on the container may be helpful in some cases.

Comment: Why do you say that "the parent container doesn't know when its children wrap"? Why wouldn't it know? It would make sense if this was the spec. But not that "it doesn't know". Browser developers could get the content width of a child and adjust its container width accordingly.

Comment: How does it happen that the container does not know about its content's wrap in terms of the width but does know about it when it comes to the height? (the container does change its height accordingly to fit its wrapped content)

Comment: @IlyaLoskutov, can you post an example? Perhaps a code sample in jsFiddle.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74431243) is my closed question on the matter in hand. `.item` acts as the container for text. When the text wraps, the container changes its height to fit it (the difference can be observed in the two pictures I've attached to) but, indeed, it don't want to shrink its width to amount to the longest line of the wrapped text. The same can be seen in [this example](https://codepen.io/Ilya-Loskutov/pen/poKWXwV) with flex box (`.internal-container` changes its height as its items wrap)

Answer (score 5):

Have a good look at my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmu6rr9o/23/) in which I changed:

- **`.holder`** `width` to `max-width` (in `.v` classes)
- modified **`.holder`** to `wrap` and `space-around` its children
- added 2 more **`.v`** classes for clarity
- removed the `<br>'s`
- and, **most importantly**, added `flex: 0 0` to **`.child`**

Flexbox almost always needs `max-width` to be set, which is more flexible than `width`.
Depending on how you need the `.child`ren to behave, modify the `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` in `flex: 0 0` to meet your needs. (the result of `flex: 1 0` looks nice too)

...no Javascript needed...

The [Codrops Flexbox Reference](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/flexbox/) is very useful to understand Flexible Box Layout.

Comment: for anybody wondering, `flex: 0 0;` does not achieve OP's requirements; it forces flex children to wrap their text even when there is enough space for it. Compare the top flex parent in the two fiddles, where there is ample horizontal space but every element's text still wraps.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your blocks behave like this is because of CSS rendering.

In the first case in you fiddle the browsers doesn't know when the block gets too small for it's content. So it keeps stretching until it reaches the maximum and then renders the text.

In your last case you tell the browser where to break so it knows that the element should not get wider.

The only way you can easily solve this is by setting the breaks yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid something like that might be happening… Still hoping some smart hacks exist, since it looks like a rather common situation…

Comment: We had a similar issue at our work where we wanted an icon to float right next to the text: http://codepen.io/WartClaes/pen/grVQrz?editors=1100. Only we bumped also into the issue that the block always renders the full width nevertheless there was a lot of whitespacing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a CSS-only solution, you can use something like `width: 100px;` to set the minimum width of the child and `flex: auto;` so that it grows.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ncvp7gzs/1

(Note this is only tested this on Chrome)