# Make <a> tag same width as text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a menu option with two links.  When the line wraps, the `<a>` tag is wider than the text it contains, making the second '+' link too far away.  Can I make the `<a>` tag just as wide as the text it contains?

```
<li class="has-submenu">
  <a href="/pages/litigation">Litigation & Dispute Resolution</a>
  <a class="expand-nav" href="#">+</a>
</li>
```

The `<li>` is `display: flex`, the `<a>`'s are `display: inline-block`.

[image: When text is on one line, the width is fine]
[image: When the text breaks to a newline, the the <a> tag is wider than the text]

Comment: Probably you'll have to include your code.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Make container shrink-to-fit child elements as they wrap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37406353/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your CSS. this will prevent the text from going to the next line, and will make it take all the space it needs.

```
.has-submenu a:nth-child(1){
     white-space:nowrap;
     width:auto;
}
```