# Flexbox - Wrap Center Item on New Line First

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using Flex Box to create a traditional float items list.  I have three items structured like:

```
<section>
    <div>
        item one
    </div>
    <div>
        item two
    </div>
    <div>
        item three
    </div>
</section>
```

with CSS:

```
section{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div{
    width: 33%;
    min-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

In this current format, `item three` will always be the first child pushed to a new line if the width of the screen drops below a threshold.

Is there anyway to configure Flex Box so that `item two` is always the first to drop?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp696hp6/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the wrapping behavior and order of flex items in a media query:

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp696hp6/3/)

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}
div {
  width: 33%;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  section { flex-wrap: wrap; }
  div:nth-child(2) { order: 1; }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>item one</div>
  <div>item two</div>
  <div>item three</div>
</section>
```

*From the spec:*

> [**5.4. Display Order: the `order` property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-property)
>
> Flex items are, by default, displayed and laid out in the same order as they appear in the source document. The 
>   `order` property can be used to change this ordering.
>
> The `order` property controls the order in which children of a flex container appear within the flex container, by 
>   assigning them to ordinal groups. It takes a single `<integer>` value, which specifies which ordinal group the flex item 
>   belongs to.

The initial `order` value for all flex items is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section>
<div>
    item one
</div>
<div>
    item two
</div>
<div>
    item three
</div>
</section>
 section{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction:column-reverse; 
 }
 div{
     width: 33%;
    min-width: 200px;
     border: 1px solid black;
```

more Examples you can find use whith @media (max-width: 600px) { [exmple one](https://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/xsfodLrx/2/) and 
[example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/vpdhcrge/1/) and [exmple 3](https://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/x6z4jg4n/1/) and [example 4](https://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/q77w4ry7/3/) and [exmple 5](https://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/Ltdf4n6s/3/) and [exmple 6](https://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/oejafevp/1/)