# Know when flex-box puts item to new row

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to know when `flex-box` puts element to new row?
I want this to happen as in this snippet [(actually jsfiddle is better so you can just resize and see)](https://jsfiddle.net/582ktjso/) but without using the

```
@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
    /* what ever code in here */
}
```

cause there might be more or less items `<li>s` inside the `<ul>` so I might not even have to put it to new row. Or I do have to put it to new row earlier or later [like in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/582ktjso/1/) where the seccond `<ul>` has only one `<li>`. So how could I achieve what I'm doing with the CSS media query without the media query? Is there a CSS way? If there is no CSS way, what would be a good javascript solution to add a class to the parent `<div>` at the right moment?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;  
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    border: solid 1px #afafaf;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
    div {
        display: block;
    }
    ul {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Tempor</li>
        <li>accusam</li>
        <li>labore</li>
        <li>sit</li>
        <li>diam</li>
        <li>aliquyam</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Consetetur</li>
        <li>sadipscing</li>
        <li>aliquyam</li>
        <li>voluptua</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not with CSS. A container doesn't know when a child element wraps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37413580/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B thank you. I just thought that there might is a `flex-box` magic solution I missed. But then I'll have to it for sure with javascript?

Comment: See the dupe I just posted.

Comment: @Michael_B yes, thank you! I didn't find that one .. thanks again!