# Elements not wrapping in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

**Hello everyone**,

Pretty new into web development, I'm trying to learn how to use the beautiful css grid tool, but I'm actually stuck with this:

I want my cards to auto-flow one by one in the next row (with the same column-template), but I'm actually only seeing one card in my browser.

I was thinking the issue is with my `.wrapper` height in `vh`. I tried `px` and `%`, but I'm really stuck to find a solution.

I really would appreciate if someone have an idea about the issue, or any comment regarding my (bad... or good ?) way of coding !

```css
/* Just some horrible stylization to better see boxes */

body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

/* Definition of the 3 grids used*/

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 3fr 1fr 3fr 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header header header header"
                       "main main main main main main main"
                       "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer"
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 7fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar box-content box-content";
}

/* This box-content's grid-template-columns have many ones, it is done to modify
only the grid-template-areas with media-queries for larger screen*/

.box-content {
  grid-area: box-content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 7fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: ". . . . . . . . ."
                       ". card card card card card card card."
                       ". . . . . . . . .";
}

/* Definition of the different element's grid-area*/

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}


.card {
  grid-area: card;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
 <!-- I apologize for non-semantic tags, only a quick prototyping -->

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header"> Header Header Header Header Header</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="sidebar">Sidebar Sidebar </div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
        <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
        <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
        <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"> Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer </div>
  </div>
```

***Thanks***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your cards to wrap, row-by-row, use the `auto-fit` and `minmax` functions.

Here's a full explanation: [Getting columns to wrap in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43662552/3597276)

Here's a basic demo: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfox8gr5/) (re-size the browser width to see the effect)

Here's the demo code:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 3fr 1fr 3fr 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header header header header"
                       "main main main main main main main"
                       "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer"
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 7fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar box-content box-content";
}

.box-content {
  grid-area: box-content;
  align-items: start;
  align-content: start;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.header  { grid-area: header; }
.sidebar { grid-area: sidebar; }
.footer { grid-area: footer; }


body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"> Header Header Header Header Header</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar Sidebar </div>
    <div class="box-content">
      <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
      <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
      <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
      <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
      <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
      <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
      <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
      <div class="card"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"> Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Just some horrible stylization to better see boxes */

body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

/* Definition of the 3 grids used*/

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 3fr 1fr 3fr 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header header header header"
                       "main main main main main main main"
                       "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer"
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 7fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar box-content box-content";
}

/* This box-content's grid-template-columns have many ones, it is done to modify
only the grid-template-areas with media-queries for larger screen*/

.box-content {
  grid-area: box-content;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 7fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row; padding:20px;
  
  
}

/* Definition of the different element's grid-area*/

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}


.card-1 {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%; margin-bottom:20px; min-height:500px;
 
  
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Layout 1</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- I apologize for non-semantic tags, only a quick prototyping -->

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header"> Header Header Header Header Header</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="sidebar">Sidebar Sidebar </div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div class="card-1"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
        <div class="card-1"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
        <div class="card-1"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
        <div class="card-1"> Card Card Card Card Card Card </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"> Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

can you please check your solution

and more example - https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and the link, i will definetly chet it out, but i think i must clarify what i want to do (my english isn't the best), and a image is the best way i think : [Image](https://ibb.co/hDoXrv). I would like cards to go all in the middle column, row by row (and add an overflow: scroll on the .box-content