# CSS Grid auto-fill columns of different widths

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Rather than rely on media queries, I've been trying to create a responsive component using css grid so that it'll make use of available space in different layouts. If the space is large enough there should be two columns, the first is fixed width (containing an image) and the second takes the remainder (with text), a 2x1 grid. If it's not then there should be a single column taking all available space and the grid changes to 1x2, e.g.

**Wide 2x1 grid**

```
+---+---------+
| o | text    |
+---+---------+
```

**Narrow 1x2 grid**

```
+---------+
|    o    |
+---------+
| text    |
+---------+
```

I looked at using `repeat(auto-fill, ...)` with multiple column dimensions but then it repeats that 2 column pattern, which makes sense but doesn't solve my problem. I'm hoping there's a way to define different widths for different `auto-fill` columns. Otherwise, I suspect there might be a solution involving `*-content`? Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Michael will know better but I think you are stuck with media queries. At some point you're goin to run foul of the implict or explicitly stated grid I suspect. CSS-Grid is a robust layout system but it *ain't magic*.

Comment: Frankly, this sound like somethng flexbox should be handling....but even then I think you'd need media queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Paulie_D, you're correct that this is better handled with flexbox, but it turns out it doesn't need media queries. Basically needs a combination of `flex-wrap: wrap` and different `flex-grow` values so the text takes the remaining space when it doesn't wrap but the image can still grow when stacked.

[**Example**](https://codepen.io/pmccloghrylaing/pen/vRmxwN)

```css
.Profile {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: .5rem;
}
.Profile-img {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background: blue;
  margin: .5rem;
}
.Profile-text {
  flex: 10 0 10em;
  background: red;
  margin: .5rem;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 600px">
  <div class="Profile">
    <div class="Profile-img">
      <img/>
    </div>
    <div class="Profile-text">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 300px">
  <div class="Profile">
    <div class="Profile-img">
      <img/>
    </div>
    <div class="Profile-text">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```