# long text inside css grid, stretches whole grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a css grid

```
#featuredRestaurantSection {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
column-gap: 10px;
row-gap: 2em;
padding: 10px;
}
```

It displays fine, with 3 columns. But whenever any column has text that is large, that text doesn't wrap inside, but stretches the whole column.

What can I do?

Comment: can you show us?

Comment: i think the answer is here in this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662552/getting-columns-to-wrap-in-css-grid

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)