# How to make a CSS grid collapse without defining a column width

Tags: css, grid-layout

I have this layout:

[image]

Basically the HTML and CSS is the following:

```
<style>
  section { display: grid, grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) };
  div::first-child: { grid-column: 1/3}
</style>
<section>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</section>
```

when the viewport becomes smaller, I want the grid to have 2 columns and then 1 column. I could use media-queries and redefine the number of columns but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do that using `auto-fill` function?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662552/getting-columns-to-wrap-in-css-grid) shows how to do it by defining the width of the columns, but ideally I wouldn't want to do that and have the width based on the available space for the number of columns.

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding media queries?

Comment: @BradyWard, no, this question is for educational purposes

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS-Grid does not have this as an option other than the link you already have.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I see, thanks. So is it correct to conclude that the number of columns in CSS grid should always be defined by `grid-template-columns` using either explicit number of auto-fill with a specified column width? Or can the number of columns also be defined by the content width?

Comment: Your first assumption is correct.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I see, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This little tidbit works pretty well. You have to have a min-width, and that controls the breakpoints. We generally set this to be approx 100% (less margins) of a mobile viewport screen-ish.

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
```