# How display specific no. of rows in css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using **CSS grid** to display 5 cards. The cards aligned perfectly in a single row in desktop.
But, when I switch to a **mobile device**, they are displayed as per the **image below**.

Is it possible to specify to **display only two rows** in the **CSS grid**.

[image]

Comment: do you mean you need to hide div 5 in mobile ?

Comment: You really can't as CSS-Grid will create *implicit* rows for any wrapping. On mobile how many items should there be in each row?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Possibly related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662552/getting-columns-to-wrap-in-css-grid 
In case you want to hide the 5th element just set "display: none" in a media query.

Comment: Hi @NipunTharuksha, yes I meant to hide 5th div in mobile.

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D on a mobile only 2 items should be there in each row. And it will be helpful it you could elaborate a little for the downvote? :)

Comment: Hi @Kruspe can you please elaborate for which should I set display none? The container of the divs or the div itself?

Comment: @VinaySharma SHOW YOUR CODE

Answer (score 2):

*You cannot specify only 2 rows* **but** you can try to set the last rows to a `minmax(0,0)` value aside `overflow:hidden;` ... 
 to hide them :

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, 1fr) minmax(100px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 0); /* third-row won't show, next might , grid-gap will increase height of section if set */
}

section {
  counter-reset: divs;
}

div {
  border: solid;
}

div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs)
}
p:before {
color:red;
  content: counter(divs)
  }
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
<p> boxes are standing here </p>
```

this hides the third row, if more , some element will show up since a `grid-gap` set will increase `height` for each extra rows.

---

You may use `margin` instead `grid-gap` and add for each extra rows to hide  the `mimax(0,0)` value for the `grid-template-rows`.

**Another demo below** showing a single row (out of 7)  and 2 boxes (out of 14).

```css
section {counter-reset:divs;}
div {border:solid;margin:0.5em;}
div:before {counter-increment:divs;content:counter(divs)}

section {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;   
  overflow:hidden;
  grid-template-rows: 
    minmax(100px,1fr) /* row to be seen */
    minmax(0,0)
    minmax(0,0)
    minmax(0,0)  
    minmax(0,0) 
    minmax(0,0)  
    minmax(0,0)  ;/* 7 rows values set , 6 rows can be hidden */
}

p:before {
color:red;
  content: counter(divs)
  }
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
</section>
<p> boxes are standing here.</p>
```

[demo (hide/show) so many rows](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PoqNoxg)

Comment: Hi, that's not working as expected because if I try to hide second row as well, the second row is being displayed a little bit and is not being hidden completely.

Comment: @VinaySharma remove the grid-gap and use margin instead. ;) like the second example i have made explaining this case. i'll edit the second snippet example to show a single row .

Comment: Thanks for sharing that point. Actually I was using `grid-gap: 10px` which was adding a gap both horizontally as well as vertically, instead used `grid-gap: 0 10px` which is now being applied only horizontally.

Comment: @VinaySharma great, i've made a demo from the last snippet where you can choose amount of rows to show/hide. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PoqNoxg

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for that. That's an amazing job! Well, I have posted another question if you could help me with :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/60238044/11220479

Answer (score 0):

You can work with css. Either you create a mobile-display-none class that will hide your content at a specific breakpoint. Or if you're receiving this data from an arrayyou can modify the array or specify in code wich index the items should be rendered to. However you will need a breakpoint for that as well so i'd just go for straight css @media screen. If you'd like to make the 5th div as third element in that row you might want to adjust your grid.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the last element in case the grid wraps. I made a working example.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
</div>
```

--

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
      grid-auto-flow: row;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(300px, 500px));
  }
  .e{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k2zLqx1d/

Comment: Hi, my requirement is to have common class for all div. Let's suppose I have 100's of such div then it won't be feasible to specify class name as a, b, c, d.. and so on for all.