# Css Grid: How to set columns to wrap depending on the content length?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have seen several kind of similar questions, but none answers my question.

I am trying to make a [questionnaire with multiple choice](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7bzq1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss). I have the choices styled in css grid. If I have a grid track with 3 columns, how can I dynamically change the number of columns to 2 if content in one of the columns cannot fit in one of the three columns?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662552/getting-columns-to-wrap-in-css-grid) among other solutions but it did not work.

Here is [my current implementaion](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7bzq1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

**EDIT:** It is not a must I do it with css grid. A solution using Flexbox would still be great.

Comment: so why are you using the grid for this, I have seen your code, You can achieve this by flex as well. is it mandatory to use GRID?

Comment: @Atul no it is not mandatory to use grid. I can also use flex. Could you please show me how I could do it with flex? Thank you.