# How to control wrapping position of child divs within parent?

Tags: html, css

Run my snippet below at full screen and adjust the screen size to see how the images in the last row stack/wrap. They wrap into the next row directly centered underneath. I want them to wrap to the left.

```css
#instafeed{
  text-align: center; 
}

#instafeed a {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="instafeed">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BXnys9RjRPz/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/20688297_1963514993937753_857460435048202240_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BWxTrtyDxRc/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.29.629.629/20213856_1910698219205963_6930800772938465280_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BWNScFZjAgh/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c119.0.841.841/19761754_1559014790783970_446056229412798464_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BHUleLojUFQ/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13556807_1737478323176649_1504794082_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BGuK4Fcj8b1/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13391183_147579948992940_1044739645_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BFCIh_Oj8YZ/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13117875_1540501896252889_1217427591_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BEfKRBvj8Qd/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12960149_1093357414043915_1709258515_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BD4AKj0D8Qk/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12912710_1541744086121735_865068036_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDdgvkqj8eB/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12905230_1339824306033837_360303890_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDWgGqED8V_/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/11931255_1744543129098475_1731252403_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDUiP0ZD8eE/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12277558_561257480701059_1294228914_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDRJGqgj8be/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12816783_205447836492901_702305080_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYvhOj8dx/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12822483_1128921290474375_1930798468_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYno8j8dm/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.75.766.766/12797898_1144014128964808_1934723307_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYhs6j8dZ/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12751172_1698911350393552_1669259430_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYcOpD8dP/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/10631982_1516921725284348_987033499_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCl2NgfD8fS/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12783854_1718490315031227_197281851_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCl2GKBD8fF/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12530847_1697788697165860_206292143_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCWZ8Ykj8cH/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.117.937.937/12748280_174729976240065_1868201851_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/1GTMoAD8bd/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/11116793_1623276567903955_143681467_n.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You **can** but they won't line up...https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qPxwrx Either you want them centered or you don't...it's pretty much that simple.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if theres a way to keep the images flush?

Comment: They **are** inside the container...

Comment: Yea I just realized that.

Comment: I want them centred in the div, but I want them to wrap to the left! Theres gotta be a way.

Comment: Not using the layout method you are using. CSS Grid *can* do that...I think.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the only non-"hack" way to do this, AFAIK, is with CSS-Grid

```css
#instafeed {
  background: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 160px);
  grid-auto-rows: 160px;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="instafeed">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BXnys9RjRPz/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/20688297_1963514993937753_857460435048202240_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BWxTrtyDxRc/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.29.629.629/20213856_1910698219205963_6930800772938465280_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BWNScFZjAgh/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c119.0.841.841/19761754_1559014790783970_446056229412798464_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BHUleLojUFQ/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13556807_1737478323176649_1504794082_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BGuK4Fcj8b1/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13391183_147579948992940_1044739645_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BFCIh_Oj8YZ/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13117875_1540501896252889_1217427591_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BEfKRBvj8Qd/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12960149_1093357414043915_1709258515_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BD4AKj0D8Qk/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12912710_1541744086121735_865068036_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDdgvkqj8eB/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12905230_1339824306033837_360303890_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDWgGqED8V_/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/11931255_1744543129098475_1731252403_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDUiP0ZD8eE/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12277558_561257480701059_1294228914_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDRJGqgj8be/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12816783_205447836492901_702305080_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYvhOj8dx/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12822483_1128921290474375_1930798468_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYno8j8dm/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.75.766.766/12797898_1144014128964808_1934723307_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYhs6j8dZ/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12751172_1698911350393552_1669259430_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYcOpD8dP/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/10631982_1516921725284348_987033499_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCl2NgfD8fS/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12783854_1718490315031227_197281851_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCl2GKBD8fF/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12530847_1697788697165860_206292143_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCWZ8Ykj8cH/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.117.937.937/12748280_174729976240065_1868201851_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/1GTMoAD8bd/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/11116793_1623276567903955_143681467_n.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! Looks like it should, right? For anyone interested, heres the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)

Comment: Seems to ...but at the moment we're obviously working with images all the same size. I'd suggest further testing as this may be fragile when extending.

Comment: True. But there are ways to normalize the size and ratio of images in a case like this. As long as the browsers understand `display: grid;` this is something one can work with.

Answer (score 0):

Now **that** was easy: What about `text-align: left;` ?

```css
#instafeed{
  text-align: left; 
}

#instafeed a {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="instafeed">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BXnys9RjRPz/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/20688297_1963514993937753_857460435048202240_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BWxTrtyDxRc/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.29.629.629/20213856_1910698219205963_6930800772938465280_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BWNScFZjAgh/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c119.0.841.841/19761754_1559014790783970_446056229412798464_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BHUleLojUFQ/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13556807_1737478323176649_1504794082_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BGuK4Fcj8b1/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13391183_147579948992940_1044739645_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BFCIh_Oj8YZ/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13117875_1540501896252889_1217427591_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BEfKRBvj8Qd/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12960149_1093357414043915_1709258515_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BD4AKj0D8Qk/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12912710_1541744086121735_865068036_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDdgvkqj8eB/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12905230_1339824306033837_360303890_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDWgGqED8V_/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/11931255_1744543129098475_1731252403_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDUiP0ZD8eE/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12277558_561257480701059_1294228914_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDRJGqgj8be/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12816783_205447836492901_702305080_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYvhOj8dx/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12822483_1128921290474375_1930798468_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYno8j8dm/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.75.766.766/12797898_1144014128964808_1934723307_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYhs6j8dZ/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12751172_1698911350393552_1669259430_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCmYcOpD8dP/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/10631982_1516921725284348_987033499_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCl2NgfD8fS/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12783854_1718490315031227_197281851_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCl2GKBD8fF/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12530847_1697788697165860_206292143_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCWZ8Ykj8cH/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.117.937.937/12748280_174729976240065_1868201851_n.jpg"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/1GTMoAD8bd/"><img src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/11116793_1623276567903955_143681467_n.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: *No*. I tried that. When you align the images to the left, they become off-centered within the parent div. I want the images to be centered within the parent but I want them to wrap to the left. Inspect the parent div to see what I mean.

Comment: I see. I did a little research as i tried to solve this. Unfortunately, a container doesn't seem to know when it's children wrap. So it can't react to that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406353/make-container-shrink-to-fit-child-elements-as-they-wrap
Maybe you'll have to use something like [masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Hm I see. Thanks I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Good luck finding a solution.