# Break element on overflow from _left_ side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an unordered list of **3** items. They're displayed in a row when space permits; however, on smaller viewports, I'm wondering if it is possible that the *first* element in the list breaks to the next line, instead of the last element. The markup here is flexible, and in both scenarios, elements are left-aligned.

Edit: there are no breakpoints / media queries. I'm looking for a solution that does not rely on different CSS at different breakpoints.

---

Larger screens:

`| item1 | item2 | item3 --------------- |`

Smaller screens:

`| item2 | item3 --- |` (item 1 breaks down and is hidden)

---

What I've tried:

- items: float:right; and display:inline-block; (breaks correctly, but doesn't respect left alignment)
- direction:rtl;  and reversed order of items in markup (same issue as above)
- variations on flex-direction and align-items on the items parent

---

In all instances I can get kinda close to what I need, but am still missing a core criteria. Is this even possible?

A fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/me5sbzqy/1/

Comment: When you toggle in the small screen, also add `order: 1` to the first list item.

Comment: ah - to clarify, there are no breakpoints here. In the fiddle, the toggle is there just to quickly test ideas

Comment: You can write media query based on small resolution and apply different css to your first item.

Comment: Yes. I understand. But the concept still applies.

Comment: @Michael_B - I'm still not following. Adding `order:1` will change the order when all items are displayed. How would this work on both large and small screens ?

Comment: You would need a media query for this to work. The container has no concept of when it's children wrap. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413580/3597276