# How to prevent flex-items from overflowing flex parent with no wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with `flex-direction: row`. The child items have a `min-width` set. When the window is shrunk past the point where the `min-width` is reached, the items begin to overflow the flex container.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  min-width: 100px;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4t8029q8/

Is there any way to force the container to stretch to contain the items without setting an explicit `min-width` on the parent? Doing so provides the behavior I am trying to achieve, but is too rigid to accomodate a variable number of items.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 330px
}

.child {
  min-width: 100px;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4t8029q8/1/

This is what I want, for the flex-items to never overflow the flex container even if it causes the page to need a horizontal scroll.

NOTE: I have other more complicated logic requiring `flex-basis: 0px` and `flex-grow: 1`, so those lines cannot be removed.

Comment: The code snippets added by the edits don't actually show the problem due to browser width limitations on chrome. The jsfiddle link is still the best way to view the current/desired behavior.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Set `display: inline-flex` on the `.parent` class to change it to an inline element. This will also force the `.parent` to expand to contain its children. Then by setting `min-width: 100%` on the `.parent` class, it will force it to expand to 100% of the containing element.

```
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.child {
  min-width: 100px;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;

  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: *This will also force the `.parent` to expand to contain its children.* Correct. This is no different than `display: flex` in terms of the parent container. The width of the container never changes.

Comment: The only difference (which appears to be key in this case) is that with `inline-flex` the children are prevented from overflowing the container.

Comment: `min-width: 1px;` on the child that was stretching solved the problem for me.

Comment: In my case, simply adding `min-width` on the child, worked; I did not use `inline-flex` on the parent.

Comment: All I needed was `min-width` on the parent

Comment: The answer is weird, but the top comment works like a charm! Now I just need someone to explain *why*...

Answer (score 5):

You're forcing your child elements to have a specific width, much like @Michael_B mentioned, this essentially creates a static environment where they will remain the set width regardless of the parent.

Essentially at this point, since you know the min-width of your children elements, I would create a media query, at the specific width requirement, which in this case is 100px. Once your screen reaches said size, force your parent to have wrapping items by adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your parent. When you're outside the said width, be sure to set your parent's CSS back to not allow wrapping, `flex-wrap: nowrap;` . This will allow your child items to wrap, and your parent will create a horizontal to the page.

Comment: unfortunately can't allow wrapping in this instance

Answer (score 1):

you can use `overflow-y: auto` on the `parent` container, if scrolling doesn't matter you.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-y: auto;/*add this.*/
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  min-width: 100px;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: scrolling on the page is what I'm looking for, but can't have a scroll on the div itself unfortunately.

Comment: You can use `display: inline-flex` on parent container instead. But it contains the overall size of its children.

The other way around is using media-queries. When the display-size reaches the desired minimum width, then change the `display: flex` to `display: inline-flex`

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the container to re-size fluidly in order to prevent the child elements from overflowing. This is dynamic behavior, which is the realm of JavaScript, not HTML or CSS.

Because the HTML and CSS rendering engines do not automatically re-flow the source documents when child elements overflow their container, there is no way for the container to know when the children have overflowed and, therefore, expand. You're in a static environment. The concept applies to wrapping, as well.

Here's a more detailed explanation (that covers wrapping behavior, but applies to overflow, as well):

- [Make container shrink-to-fit child elements as they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37406353/3597276)

You'll need a script or possibly media queries to make your layout work as desired.

Comment: was going to accept, but Roberts answer actually works with no rigid widths needing to be set. care to comment on how his answer is getting around what you explained?

Comment: That answer doesn't actually answer your question: *"How to force flex parent to stretch to fit child items?"* The flex parent never expands; it remains fixed. That was the issue that I addressed, which remains valid. However, that answer does prevent the children from overflowing, which seems to be what you actually needed (so I +1). I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: it does expand though? I can shrink the window all the way down to where the min-width is enforced (and the items do not overflow) or grow the window as large as I want and the flex-items / parent grow unhindered. EDIT: not arguing by the way I just want to understand.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. But still, there's no expansion. In your code, the container shrinks below the size of the content (never expands). In the accepted answer, it stops shrinking at the content `min-width` (but again, never expands).

Comment: Just to be clear, since the container covers, in all cases, 100% width of the viewport, I'm not talking about screen re-sizing (where there is obvious container expansion). I'm talking about the container expanding to accommodate child elements.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. "Expand" is the wrong term since 100% width will "expand" with the window, but is actually a static width. Rather, it has an implicit `min-width` equal to its contents due to the `inline-flex`. As you said, preventing the overflow is really what I was after and `inline-flex` is an elegant way to do that. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes. We're on the same page now :-)