# Remove gap between items when text wraps

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the dash to be vertically centered with the text on the right and I want them to be 10px apart. But when I'm using flex, the text on the right wraps normally, but takes more than its content's actual size, and now the gap between the two spans is too wide. Is there an elegant solution to this ?

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

span.dash {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="dash">-</span><span>+ 10€ pour séance à domicile (déplacement inclus)</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *"Is there an elegant solution to this?"* Not with CSS alone. In CSS / HTML a container has no idea when its content wraps. So it doesn't adjust its size accordingly. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37406353/3597276

Comment: That might be it, I managed to do what I want with absolute positioning but it's not super elegant

Comment: Right. Not elegant. But hacks exist for a reason. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it, but I'm not too happy with it. Here it is :

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

span.dash {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-300%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="dash">-</span><span>+ 10€ pour séance à domicile (déplacement inclus)</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That sucks... I will keep looking into it

Answer (score 0):

Use `word-break: break-all;` working fine

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left:15px;
}
span{
  display: block;
  word-break: break-all;
}
span.dash {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="dash">-</span><span>+ 10€ pour séance à domicile (déplacement inclus) 10€ pour séance à domicile (déplacement inclus) </span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I do want to keep the text centered

Answer (score 0):

To align  to the right you need to put the display: flex property on the parent element.

If I understand your question, the solution is:
jsfiddle.net/gabrielpito/y6jog29x/

Comment: I want the elements to be side by side

Comment: like this? jsfiddle.net/gabrielpito/y6jog29x/6/

Comment: It looks better, but the elements are not vertically centered in your example

Comment: and now? jsfiddle.net/gabrielpito/y6jog29x/9/

Comment: It's the dash and the text that I want to have vertically centered

Comment: sorry now I think it's ok jsfiddle.net/gabrielpito/y6jog29x/14/

Comment: I hope it is so jsfiddle.net/gabrielpito/y6jog29x/26/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/gabrielpito/y6jog29x/27/

Comment: there are 2 examples, one without "break-all" and one with

Comment: The word break all on does what I want, but it's not very readable... Thanks