# Shrink div to fit content when content wraps

Tags: html, css

I have a set of divs that contain a variable number of children where the div forms the background color of the "element". When the children wrap, the width of the div defaults to 100%, as shown in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/henrikpewpew/pen/NWPjbPg). What I'm looking for is a way to make the div end at the rightmost child, like [[image: example]

Thanks for any help!

```css
.container {
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

.tagcontainer {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: blue;
 padding-left: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.tag {
 float: left;
 padding: 3px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.tag:not(:last-child) {
 margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="tagcontainer">
  <div class="tag">Lorem</div>
  <div class="tag">Ipsum</div>
  <div class="tag">Dolor</div>
  <div class="tag">Si</div>
  <div class="tag">Amet</div>
  <div class="tag">Consectetur</div>
  <div class="tag">fghfghfghfghfghfghfghhjghghj</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make container shrink-to-fit child elements as they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406353/make-container-shrink-to-fit-child-elements-as-they-wrap)

Comment: Look at this...
https://codepen.io/AiAbdrrahim/pen/xxbdRWx