# Whenever text-wraps make flex-box shrink and remove spacing

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. Whenever the text-wraps the h1 stays the original size making the icon float with quite some space on the right of the h1. What I would like is that the icon will always be directly next to the text even if the text wraps on a new line. Is this possible?
To show what I mean you would have to switch your browser to responsive mode and resize the screen.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is a long text for testing!</h1>
  <i class="icon">icon</i>
</div>
```

[image: Without spacing]

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox, the `.container` does not know when the content of flex-items it holds have wrapped. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413580/16094181) for a good explanation about this.
Depending on your exact requirement, a solution here could be to do this without `flex`. You could just have the icon within the `<h1>` tag and resize it as required. See the code below. You can change the `font-size` of the `.icon` class and adjust its position vertically with some padding/margin if required.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.icon { 
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is a long text for testing!<i class="icon">icon</i></h1>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but setting flex shrink to 0 fixes this I believe. The container its in is a flex container, meaning the items within it are flex items. Each one of these items has a shrink/grow/basis value. setting shrink to 0, stops its from doing what it defaults to (becoming smaller as the container space reduces).

Comment: Describe your response in code, It is really beneficial to comprehend