# Place div to the right side of the text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div with a fixed width.
It has two children:

1. First one containing text,
2. The second one is something like a "badge" (just a div with fixed width and height).

So I want to achieve something like this:-

[image]

I want **the second child to be located right next to the text of the first child**

I've tried to solve this issue by adding `display: flex` to the parent, but the problem is that the first child takes width more than its contents (example in the snippet below)

I've tried to add `flex-basis: 0` to the first child, but then each word starts with a new line, even if there is enough place to display the whole text in one line.

Maybe there is another solution?
I've tried to solve the issue using absolute positioned child but failed also.

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.first-child {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.first-child span {
  outline: 1px solid white;
}


.second-child {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <span>Loooooooong teeeeeext</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <span>Short text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe this question can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406353/make-container-shrink-to-fit-child-elements-as-they-wrap

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `width` as `min-content;` for your text element.

For example:

```css
width: min-content;
```

Comment: In this case, all words will be moved to the next line, even if the text is short and can fit on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to solve with the js code after documentReady!

```
document.querySelectorAll('.first-child').forEach(t => {t.style.width=t.querySelector('span').offsetWidth+'px'})
```

---

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.first-child').forEach(t => {t.style.width=t.querySelector('span').offsetWidth+'px'})
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.first-child {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.first-child span {
  outline: 1px solid white;
}


.second-child {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <span>Loooooooong teeeeeext</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <span>Short text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `display: inline` propert in right text. and use `display: block` property in parent div.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to add "flex: 0 0 auto;" on the ".first-child".

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.first-child {
  outline: 1px solid red;
flex: 0 0 auto; 
}

.first-child span {
  outline: 1px solid white;
}


.second-child {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <span>Loooooooong <br>teeeeeext</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <span>Short text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've added the <br /> tag to the text in the first child.
But it is dynamic, and for example it may come from the backend

Comment: Remove the <br> and now it follows the content but i think that you really need is a good old fashion "width" on the ".first-child".

Comment: Or better yet: a "max-width".

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses an addition to the HTML contents, which won't work for dynamic contents, but I'll post it nevertheless – for fixed content it works:

If you just add a linebreak / `<br/>` tag beween the words in your long text, it does what you want (no other changes to your code necessary):

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.first-child {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.first-child span {
  outline: 1px solid white;
}


.second-child {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <span>Loooooooong<br/>teeeeeext</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <span>Short text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what you are looking for to make the 2nd div to take the right end you can use `justify-content: space-between;`

Update: I misread the question, I've made changes in code and it works as expected using CSS.

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.first-child {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  flex: .5;
}

.first-child span {
  outline: 1px solid white;
}

.second-child {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <span>Loooooooong teeeeeext</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <span>Short text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only HTML/CSS way to get what ur looking for. Let me know if this works.