# How to start a new line and align the newline with another item within flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have a flexbox with different items inside.

[image]

When it wraps onto a new line I want to align this new line with the 2nd item on the first row of the flexbox, but I can't figure out how to do this. The width of the elements will be  dynamic, based on the text inside.

[image]

```css
div {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.parent { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
}

.unique_element {
  background-color: Crimson;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="unique_element">First</div>
  <div class="child">Second</div>
  <div class="child">Third</div>
  <div class="child">Fourth</div>
  <div class="child">Fifth</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two divs inside the parent div, one that holds the unique element and one that holds generic children. That's how you get the separation

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="unique-wrapper">
    <div class="unique_element">First</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child-wrapper">
    <div class="child">Second</div>
    <div class="child">Third</div>
    <div class="child">Fourth</div>
    <div class="child">Fifth</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Style the CSS as shown. Note .unique-wrapper has flex: 3 because you set the width of the element as 30%.

```css
div {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.parent { 
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

.unique_element {
  background-color: Crimson;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.unique-wrapper, .child-wrapper {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.unique-wrapper {
  flex: 3;
}

.child-wrapper {
  flex: 7;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  width: auto;
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/simonzhao7/pen/YzEvmrm?editors=1100) if you want to play with the code.

Answer (score 2):

> When it wraps onto a new line I want to align this new line with the 2nd item on the first row of the flexbox.

So, the real question is: **How to re-arrange flex items when wrapping occurs?**

Since HTML and CSS, by themselves, have [no concept of when elements wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413580/3597276), they have no control of this situation. You have to handle it, either with media queries or JavaScript.

Once you've selected your method for detecting the wrap, you can use the `order` property to re-arrange the items.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @MichaelBenjamin's fantastic answer:

> Since HTML and CSS, by themselves, have [no concept of when elements wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406353/make-container-shrink-to-fit-child-elements-as-they-wrap/37413580#37413580), they have no control of this situation. You have to handle it, either with media queries or JavaScript.

You can work around this by setting a new parent element and nest the unique element as the first child. Set this new `master-parent` to `display: flex;`.

```css
div {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
}

.unique_element {
  background-color: Crimson;
  width: 30%;
  height: 27px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.master-parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="master-parent">
  <div class="unique_element">First</div>
  <div class="parent">

    <div class="child">Second</div>
    <div class="child">Third</div>
    <div class="child">Fourth</div>
    <div class="child">Fifth</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a dummy element for spacing

```css
div {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.parent { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
}

.unique_element {
  background-color: Crimson;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.hideme{
   visibility:invisible;
   background-color:white;
   border:none;
   }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="unique_element">First</div>
  <div class="child">Second</div>
  <div class="child">Third</div>
  <div class="unique_element hideme"></div>
  <div class="child">Fourth</div>
  <div class="child">Fifth</div>
</div>
```