# How to collapse empty space in two-column flexbox text layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width, multiline

I want to remove the empty space in two-column text layouts, like this:[image]

This is a flex container with two columns containing (potentially) multi-line text. It looks fine when the text is all on one line (there's no empty space generated then), but there's empty space when the lines break.

Here's the basic HTML/CSS:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  /* How to ensure width is only as long as needed? */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">assadfsadfsadfsadf assadfsadfsadfsadf</div>
  <div class="child">assadfsadfsadfsadf assadfsadfsadfsadf</div>
</div>
```

Link to CodePen: https://codepen.io/robkom/pen/jOXyzKE

Comment: That is simply the way words wrap in HTML much like any text editor like Word or such. It works fine with shorter words or you may add `word-break: break-all;` to your container.

Comment: I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406353/make-container-shrink-to-fit-child-elements-as-they-wrap and it seems to be asking a similar question. I think what I want may not be possible with CSS alone, but maybe there's some new techniques since that question was posted (CSS or JS even).

Comment: Could you clarify what is it you exactly want? And does my proposed solution not satisfy your needs?

Comment: Are you really going to have such long strings of text? It works fine with normal-length words. There will always be a bit of white space to the right unless you use `text-align: justify`.