# How do I prevent a two span div to make a single column wider?

Tags: css, css-grid, multiple-columns

I've got a two column layout in a grid where I want the columns to have the width they need.
This works when I have two columns.
But when I add a div that spans two columns,
the smallest column becomes wider than it needs to be.
Causing the wide column to wrap when it's not needed.

The following code:

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto">
    <div>Small text</div>
    <div>Longer text that needs more space</div>
    <div style="grid-column: span 2">
        A very long text that needs so much space
        I will give it two columns
    <div>   
<div>
```

Produces the following:

[image: Result of above html code]

As you can see, for some reason the text "space" is placed on a second line.
The code without the very long text will show it on one line.

How do I get it on one line, with the very long text in two columns?

Comment: Possibly related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406353/make-container-shrink-to-fit-child-elements-as-they-wrap

Comment: Sorry @Paulie_D your question is about display:flex, I've got a problem with display:grid. I want to have multiple row's in two columns. Put only one double and one single column row in the example to simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr`:

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto 1fr; column-gap:.4em;">
  <div>Small text</div>
  <div>Longer text that needs more space</div>
  <div style="grid-column: span 2">
    A very long text that needs so much space
    I will give it two columns
  <div>   
<div>
```