CSS Wrapping Issue: Prevent Words from Expanding to Fill Row on Wrap
I'm struggling with a Flexbox layout issue where I want a specific wrapping behavior for words inside a <span> classed as keep-together. The requirement is for the words to stay together on the same line as much as possible, wrapping to a new line only when the container is too narrow to fit them side by side.
Here is the CSS I'm currently using for the .keep-together:
  .keep-together {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background-color: #ffd700; /* visual aid to see the span */
    overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  }



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Responsive Text Wrapping with Container Queries</title>
<style>
  .container {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    resize: both; /* allows you to resize the container in the browser for testing */
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%; /* initial width, adjustable for testing */
    margin: 20px auto; /* centering the container */
  }


  .keep-together {
      display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background-color: #ffd700; /* visual aid to see the span */
    overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  }

  .keep-together > span{
    background-color: blue;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">Watch how <span class="keep-together">
                                <span>word1</span>
                                <span>word2</span>
                <span>word3</span> 
                            </span>
                wrap based on container size.
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>



Desired Behavior:

The words within the keep-together should stay on the same line under normal conditions, even when that means moving all words together to a new line.
Only if the container's width is so small that all words cannot fit on a single line at all, should they break into separate lines.
Each word should only take up as much width as necessary when wrapped onto separate lines, and their container should not expand to fill the entire avaialble space.

Current Issue:
Currently, when the container's width forces the words to wrap, the container stretches to occupy the full width of the available space, which is not desired. I need the words to wrap together to a new line however follow up content should also appear on the same line as the wrapped word and not on a separate line.

Attempts to Resolve:
I have  also tried using display: inline-block. Both attempts, however, have led to the words expanding to fill the full container width upon wrapping, which is not the desired outcome.
I am looking for a pure CSS solution that can facilitate this nuanced wrapping behavior. Does anyone have suggestions or insights on how to adjust CSS Flexbox or other properties to achieve this behavior?
Thank you in advance for your help and insights!

But I suspect this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406353/make-container-shrink-to-fit-child-elements-as-they-wrap

@Paulie_D Thank you for the feedback, I added a code snippet to illustrate the problem

a very quick solution to your problem might be getting rid of the .keep-together container at all. If you then style those span with a specific class having a css rule giving display: inline-block; they will also correctly wrap instead of overflowing. Now the only problem remains the gap between them... that could be removed just removing the newline between each of those elements in the html. That's because their parent takes those new line into account rendering its content causing the gap.

To remove them it could be as easy as using font-size: 0 on the parent and have specific children for each text content. I didn't post it as an answer because actually it still doesn't fulfill the exact scenario where you want your .text container to have text nodes without their corresponding span container. If any text content had its own span and the newline were ruled by <br>s, that could be a layout that fulfill the request.

@Diego D, if I remove the keep-together class, then requirement 1 from desired behaviour will not work anymore. I want the words to change lines together and only when they don't fit alltogether on the same line, only then wrap.
